# Why I cannot use {"a", "b"} as an input for String array method parameter

Tags: java

I was wondering, why I cannot use {"a", "b"} as an input for String array method parameter?

```
public static void fun(String[] s) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"a", "b"};

    // OK
    fun(s);

    // This line is not accepted by compiler
    fun({"a", "b"});
}
```

Comment: That's not how java was defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [section 10.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3):

> An array is created by an array creation expression ([§15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)) or an array initializer ([§10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)).

The array initializer syntax is only valid *directly* when part of a variable declaration. Anywhere else - including later assignments - you have to use an array creation expression:

```
fun(new String[] { "a", "b" });
```

I suspect that makes the language simpler in terms of how it's specified, basically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
fun(new String[]{"a","b"});
```

In java even an array of Strings is treated as object. You are expecting an object of Strings array as `fun` argument. And this object is provided by `String[]{"a","b"}` which is an `anonymous String array` which is fully constructed and initialized.